# united regular expression java

Tags: java

I am building a regular expression that controls that its size is 5, that it begins with a G (uppercase) and that the rest of characters are [a-zA-Z0-9].

What I have right now is this

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^[G].*[A-Z0-9]{5,5}");
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(id);
if (mat.matches()) {
    System.out.println("YES");
} else {
    System.out.println("NO");
}
```

It doesn't work for me, if I try it separately with the G or only with the letters and numbers it works for me but I want it all together.

Comment: The `.*` in your expression means "a sequence of any number of any characters", which is not mentioned in your requirements. Maybe you should delete that.

Comment: Hello, could you add list of valid and invalid strings you are testing?

Comment: @dariosicily It should be valid: "G12Re" or "GRr1E" and invalidate "RGh56" or "G23ERTYH"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `G` : the character `G`
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]` : an ASCII letter or digit
- `{4}` : four times

Gives:

```
Pattern.compile("G[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}")
```

Comment: Explain me wrong, the string has to be exactly 5 characters ...
For example -> Gr35E
If it were -> Gr35ED would no longer be valid, it has to be just 5 characters, no more and no less.